# How to avoid function duplication (IO and not-IO versions)

Tags: haskell

I have two functions:

```
trans_table :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Map.Map Char Char
trans_table s1 s2 = Map.fromList (zip s1 s2)

random_trans_table :: IO (Map.Map Char Char)
random_trans_table = do
    rawKey <- shuffle ascii
    let zipped = zip ascii rawKey 
    let map = Map.fromList zipped
    return map
```

First of them creates Map from two strings;  second one generates random Map.
First one returns Map.Map Char Char;  second one returns IO (Map.Map Char Char)

Now I need to lookup value from this Map and I have created two functions - one for IO Map and one for Map:

```
translate_char :: Map.Map Char Char -> Char -> Maybe Char
translate_char table c = Map.lookup c table

translate_char_io :: IO (Map.Map Char Char) -> Char -> IO (Maybe Char)
translate_char_io table c = do
    raw_table <- table
    let result = Map.lookup c raw_table
    return result
```

I don't like it because it causes code duplication.  I have already duplicate one function and if I code by this way I will need to duplicate all my functions.

Is there a way to create function which will works with Map and IO (Map) the same way ?

Comment: You almost never want to write functions that take `IO Something` as inputs, unless you're writing some kind of control structure which needs to control if/when/how many times the action is run. If you just need a value, you should make your function just take a value and use `do`-notation, `>>=` or similar at the call site to bind the result of the first action and pass it to the second.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`do`-notation, or the "bind" operator `>>=` that it de-sugars to, takes care of this for you.

Anywhere that you would have called `translate_char_io`, you can use a call to the pure function by letting the monad syntax unwrap your table for you. For example, if you want to create a random table and look up two different characters in it, you could do it this way:

```
test c1 c2 = do
    table <- random_trans_table
    return (translate_char table c1, translate_char table c2)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [liftM](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#g:7) (`import Control.Monad`) to write a converter:

```
translate_char_io table c = liftM (\table' -> translate_char table' c) table
```

Note sure why you'd want only the `table` argument to be `IO`, but it's an option. Flipping the arguments would let you get rid of the inner function for just `liftM (translate_char c) table` as well. If you want both arguments to come as `IO` actions, you can also use `liftM2`:

```
translate_get_char = liftM2 translate_char random_trans_table getChar
```

Or you can just use do-notation to use your pure function in your IO code, which is probably easiest in this case:

```
translateAndPrint = do
    table <- random_trans_table
    char <- getChar
    putChar (translate_char table char)
```